# Errors trying to connect to Kubernetes web UI

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-cli

Following instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/kubernetes/container-service-kubernetes-ui):

However, trying it results in this:

```
$ az acs kubernetes browse -g myResourcrGroup -n myK8SCluster
```

Private key file is encrypted
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/Users/sikkar/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/main.py", line 36, in main
    cmd_result = APPLICATION.execute(args)
  File "/Users/sikkar/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/application.py", line 203, in execute
    result = expanded_arg.func(params)
  File "/Users/sikkar/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 278, in __call__
    return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sikkar/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 473, in _execute_command
    reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/Users/sikkar/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 450, in _execute_command
    result = op(client, **kwargs) if client else op(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/sikkar/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acs/custom.py", line 150, in k8s_browse
    _k8s_browse_internal(name, acs_info, disable_browser, ssh_key_file)
  File "/Users/sikkar/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acs/custom.py", line 160, in _k8s_browse_internal
    _k8s_get_credentials_internal(name, acs_info, browse_path, ssh_key_file)
  File "/Users/sikkar/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acs/custom.py", line 711, in _k8s_get_credentials_internal
    '.kube/config', path_candidate, key_filename=ssh_key_file)
  File "/Users/sikkar/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acs/acs_client.py", line 49, in SecureCopy
    ssh.connect(host, username=user, pkey=pkey)
  File "/Users/sikkar/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 381, in connect
    look_for_keys, gss_auth, gss_kex, gss_deleg_creds, gss_host)
  File "/Users/sikkar/lib/azure-cli/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 622, in _auth
    raise saved_exception
```

PasswordRequiredException: Private key file is encrypted

Comment: Do you get the error log on Windows or Linux?

Comment: Do you execute `az acs kubernetes get-credentials --resource-group=myResourcrGroup --name=myK8sCluster` on your local? You could refer this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/1773) on GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the similar [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/1773) on GitHub.

Do you execute `az acs kubernetes get-credentials --resource-group=myResourcrGroup --name=myK8sCluster` on you client PC? I suggest you could check your private key and execute the command again.

You could use `azure -v` to check your Azure CLI version. My version is 0.10.9. If it does not work again, I suggest you could re-install the latest version Azure CLI.

Comment: Thanks - updating the CLI version fixed the issue